# SQL SSIS Package Exec time

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, jobs

I have a complex SQL SSIS Package. When I execute it in Visual Studio IDE takes less than an hour to execute. After deploying it to "Integration Services Catalogs" and setup a step in schedule job to execute the same package, the execution time is 5 to 7 time longer. Why does the same package executes longer  when scheduled? Appreciative any hit and inputs.

Comment: Last time I *excited* an SSIS package, it took 6 to 8 times longer. So worth it.

Comment: did you checked the steps which are taking more time and see what is the cause,wait types ?

Comment: It is the same package in VS takes 1/6 time.

Comment: Is it running against the exact same data sources?  Is the server overloaded during that time?  Is it competing with other resources (backups, maintenance, etc).  There's not a systemic difference between VS and the server that would explain that kind of difference in general.

Comment: You nailed it. There is absolutely no difference between when I run VS package vs. scheduled job. Same data set, same server, same memory, same cpu, etc.

Comment: Let me expand on this. The VS is in a server pointing to the SQL Server DEVDWSQL01. When I run the VS always less than hour. Same code deployed in DEVDWSQL01. Scheduled job running DEVDWSQL01, same code execution time 6 to 8 time longer. VS Server has 2 CPU,  2 Geg of memory a single C drive. DEVDWSQL01 has 32 CPUs, 24 Geg of memory, 4 Drives (C 86 GB, D 14 GB, E 38 GB, F 46 GB).